# When previewing XML in browser, I only want to see certain items using XSL

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want XSL to output only the first PRODUCT_IMAGE_FILE node from the first ITEM node in each PRODUCT/PRODUCT_IMAGES node into a simple list that you'd find in notepad.  I've been trying to get this to work but it's difficult.

THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO SEE, END RESULT:

```
hello/this_d_one1.jpg
hello/this_d_one33.jpg
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="test.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<products>
 <product>
  <Person>Jim</Person>
  <Product_Images>
    <item>
      <Product_Image_File>hello/this_d_one1.jpg</Product_Image_File>
    </item>
    <item>
      <Product_Image_File>hello/testNOTHISONE.jpg</Product_Image_File>
    </item>
  </Product_Images>
 </product>
 <product>
  <Person>Nancy</Person>
  <Product_Images>
    <item>
      <Product_Image_File>hello/this_d_one33.jpg</Product_Image_File>
    </item>
    <item>
      <Product_Image_File>hello/testNOTHISONE3.jpg</Product_Image_File>
    </item>
  </Product_Images>
 </product>
</products>
```

Here is my test.XSL:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="products">
      <xsl:call-template name="header" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="product" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="header">
      <xsl:for-each select="//product[1]/product_images/item/child::*" >
         <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
         <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">|</xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="product/product_images/item">
      <xsl:for-each select="child::*" >
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
         <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">|</xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: And what exactly you get with your current xsl?

Comment: i've been trying to get it to show anything but it just doesn't show. All I want to do is just get the XML to show the end result I showed up above in ANYWAY possible.

Comment: Please check your input xml there are some small (copy?) errors. E.g. `</Product_Image/File>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just displaying in your browser, you could do something like this:

**XML Input** (fixed to be well-formed)

```
<products>
    <product>
        <Person>Jim</Person>
        <Product_Images>
            <item>
                <Product_Image_File>hello/this_d_one1.jpg</Product_Image_File>
            </item>
            <item>
                <Product_Image_File>hello/testNOTHISONE.jpg</Product_Image_File>
            </item>
        </Product_Images>
    </product>
    <product>
        <Person>Nancy</Person>
        <Product_Images>
            <item>
                <Product_Image_File>hello/this_d_one33.jpg</Product_Image_File>
            </item>
            <item>
                <Product_Image_File>hello/testNOTHISONE3.jpg</Product_Image_File>
            </item>
        </Product_Images>
    </product>
</products>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="product/Product_Images[1]/item[1]/Product_Image_File[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Product_Image_File">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** (raw)

```
hello/this_d_one1.jpg<br>hello/this_d_one33.jpg<br>
```

**Output** (rendered)

hello/this_d_one1.jpg
hello/this_d_one33.jpg